# Interline agreement Azerbaijan Airlines and Turkish Airlines

Tags: air-travel, luggage, turkish-airlines

I'm arriving in Istanbul with Azerbaijan Airlines (from Teheran via Baku) and plan to connect from there with Turkish Airlines. Is it possible to check my luggage all the way through (or from Baku onwards). [The two airlines have a codesharing agreement](http://airlineroute.net/2015/03/16/tkj2-codeshare-s15/), but does this mean they will allow checking through my luggage? The flights would be on two separate tickets.

Does anyone have any experience with a similar scenario and these two airlines? What would you suggest? Is there a chance to get a definite answer beforehand or is it up to the agent at the check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an e-mail to Azerbaijan Airlines about the issue, here's their answer:

> You can ask check-in manager at the airport to check your baggage till the final destination. It depends on flight load and situation. So we can not guarantee you baggage transportation till Munich.
>
> Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 8):

A codesharing agreement is a deeper form of partnership than a ticketing or a baggage interline agreement. The existing of a codesharing partnership implies that at least a ticketing interline arrangement exists (in the same direction as the codeshare), as this is necessary for the technical implementation of a codeshare. However, a baggage interline agreement is a separate arrangement.

In this case it seems that if a baggage interline agreement has been signed, it is not yet in effect. At time of writing, J2 (Azerbaijan Airlines) has interline agreements with the following carriers.

```
   MAY ISSUE TICKETS INCLUDING
       AB  AF  AH  AI  AR  AZ  A9  BA  BD  BI  BT  B2  CA  CZ  
       DL  DV  EK  FV  FZ  HR  HU  IR  JU  KC  KE  KK  KL  LG  
       LH  LY  NG  OK  OS  OZ  PC  PK  PS  QR  RJ  SU  SV  S7  
       TK  T3  UA  U6  VS  VV  XF  Z6  6Q  7D  9U  9Y          

   MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO
       AB  AF  AH  AI  AR  AZ  A9  BA  BD  BI  BT  B2  CA  CZ  
       DL  DV  EK  FV  FZ  HR  HU  JU  KE  KK  KL  LG  LH  LY  
       NG  OK  OS  OZ  PC  PK  PS  QR  SU  SV  S7  T3  UA  U6  
       VS  VV  XF  Z6  6Q  7D  9U  9Y
```

You will note that TK (Turkish Airlines) is absent from the second category.

Further, an interline agreement for baggage is just a legal contract that enables the airlines to forward baggage to each other if they see fit in individual circumstances. The existence of the agreement doesn't mean the airline will be willing to do it across unconnected tickets.

Comment: Where do you find these tables?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ExpertFlyer.com (100 USD per year fee). The site has a connection to WorldSpan/Galileo